# How to make git change folder icon if the contents are not synched

Tags: git, github, mercurial, tortoisehg

In tortoisehg if a directory is not synched with the repository, the folder icon adds a red exclamation mark. If the folder is synched it displays a red check-mark (image below). How to active such a feature for git?

- I am using git now and if the files of the folder are not synched it does not change the folder icon at all ( no change!). This visual notation would be very helpful with git as it easily notifies you that file are not synched

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Git itself doesn't provide file manager integration (and in fact neither does Mercurial).

You've asked for a feature from TortoiseHg, a graphical tool built on top of Mercurial that provides integration with Windows Explorer. There are several similar tools for Git, each with slightly different features, but I suspect you'll be most comfortable with [TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) since it will be most similar to TortoiseHg.

TortoiseGit [shows overlay icons in Windows Explorer](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Screenshots#Overlay_icons_in_explorer).